# Trim blank lines from textarea submission

Tags: php

I have a form that submits text from textarea. The text can be formatted, i.e. have line breaks and paragraphs, however I want to remove blank lines at the end of the text. Shall I use rtrim or preg_replace?

Can I use something like this to clear blank lines, carriage returns and tabs?

```
rtrim($_POST['inviteMsg'], "\n\t\r");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In fact, that's precisely what `rtrim` is for. `preg_replace` just offers you loads of extra flexibility that you don't need in this case.

Comment: But if I add a carriage return and tap a space bar, the line is still empty but the script does not remove it...

Comment: The default value for the second argument of `rtrim` includes spaces, too, so it would remove that, too. However, it would also remove a set of trailing spaces on the last line. If you want to preserve trailing spaces on the last non-empty line but remove all empty lines, `rtrim` indeed won't cut it (no pun intended).

Comment: No, there's no need for for blank space afterwards. But I tried this code and it still keeps all the carriage returns... Odd.